# Подключение проекта С++ в проект C#

Tags: c#, c++

Есть проект на С# и проект на C++, который имеет управляемый класс.

**Вопрос:** Можно как-нибудь проект C++ подключить в проект C#? Если нет, то как сделать dll готового проекта на C++?

Comment: так а какого типа проект C++?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду управляемый или нет?

Comment: и это тоже. Но судя по тому, что есть _управляемый класс_ - проект тоже управляемый. Я имею ввиду какой тип проекта: библиотека? исполняемый файл? еще что-то?

Comment: а еще, в какой IDE ведется разработка?

Comment: По сути проект состоит только из пары файлов исходного кода, а IDE - VS 2015

Comment: можно добавить этот проект в solution к проекту c# и добавить проекту на c# ссылку на этот проект через Add Reference

Comment: Я так и пытался, только он выдавал ошибку: Убедитесь, что файл доступен и правильно собран или COM компонент. Добавлял файл .vcxproj

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44797/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Решил так: закомментировал содержимое dllmain, пересобрал проект C# и опять попробовал добавить ссылку на проект C++.